# Do I need the second "being" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, grammar

> I turned from being her patient to (being) her student.

Why or why not? I find  both instances on Google and some use *into*. So I'm a bit confused.

Comment: I think it's necessary but I can't tell exactly why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second *being* is necessary to form the contrast.
In your example,

> I went from *being* her patient to her student.

"to her student" is not correct, though it might be understood.

The pattern you are using is

> **from** *be-ing something* **to** *be-ing something-else*
>
> I went **from** "I was her patient" **to** "I am her student".
>   **Then** I was her patient, **now** I am her student.

*was*, *am*, *being* are all state of *being* verbs.
The second *being* is necessary to state what you are now.

Comment: You think it's actually necessary?  I feel like when there's that kind of parallelism in a sentence, we often omit the repetition of the verb.  I can't think of a *rule* per se, but if you google ["I went from being" you'll see the second *being* often omitted](https://www.google.com/search?q="I+went+from+being").  Same thing with ["I went from working out"](https://www.google.com/search?q="i+went+from+working+out") - you see stuff like "I went from working out six times a week to twice a week", without the repetition of "working out".

Comment: While it's true "I went from *being* single to married overnight" avoids the repetition and is understandable, something like "I went from eating meat to vegetables" doesn't sound quite right, nor does "I went from *being* a carnivore to vegetarian", as it's usually phrased as "I went from eating meat to *being* a vegetarian".

Answer (score -1):

I can give my explanation. But I could not give the the real reasons. My English teacher said that verb behind a preposition should convert into V-ing . In the sentence, both "from" and "to" are prepositions. So the second "being" should be being.

Comment: I don't think the OP was asking whether it should be *be* or *being*, he was asking whether the verb should be there at all.